# Jquery/CSS target a class in print

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add some HTML to a class...any ideas why below isn't working?

**JQUERY:**

```
$("ul#breadcrumbs li[media='print']").append("<strong>Hello</strong>");
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="breadcrumbs">   
        <li class="">
            <a href="supporting-overview.html">Supporting Units</a>
        </li>

        <li class="">
            <a href="literacy-and-learning.html">Language of geography</a>
        </li>

        <li class="active">
            <a href="literacy-and-learning.html">literacy and learning</a>
        </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: There is no li element with media attribute.

Comment: FireBug is your friend. When you run into something like this, you can check whether the selector returns anything by entering `$("ul#breadcrumbs li[media='print']")` into the console. It will show you the elements that get selected by it then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector `ul#breadcrumbs li[media='print']` looks for an `li` with attribute `media` that has the value `print` e.g. `<li media='print'>`. There is no such `li` in your html so no selection is made and no element appended.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to match a `li` element with attribute `media="print"`.Currently you don't have a single `li` element with such attribute.

For the code to work you will need to have

```
<ul id="breadcrumbs">   
        <li class="">
            <a href="supporting-overview.html">Supporting Units</a>
        </li>

        <li class="" media="print">
            <a href="literacy-and-learning.html">Language of geography</a>
        </li>

        <li class="active">
            <a href="literacy-and-learning.html">literacy and learning</a>
        </li>

</ul>

$("ul#breadcrumbs li[media='print']").append("<strong>Hello</strong>");
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Mw7j/)**

Comment: Ah sorry! I'm actually trying to add some HTML code after the anchor tag only in print mode. Is it possible?

Comment: @user1409322 Surely it is possible ,using append.

Answer (score 0):

Musa is right. jQuery will only target the tags and tag attributes defined in the html.

To achieve what you want, you can add a class to the element you wish to append

`$("ul#breadcrumbs li").append("<strong class='visible-in-print'>Hello</strong>");`

and keep this element hidden in all media types except `media @print`

```
.visible-in-print {
    display: none;
}

@media print {
    .visible-in-print { 
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about this?

'$('<style media="print">ul#breadcrumbs li{font-weight:bold;}</style>').append(' Hello ');'

Answer (score 0):

I tried this

```
$( document ).attr( 'style', '@media print { body { font-size: 15pt } }' )
```